# Flutter - Unable to retrieve data from Firestore after successful login and registration

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

So, I want to display the name of my App's current user in my home screen after logging in/ after successful registration.

The user data is getting properly stored in the firebase cloud Firestore but when I try to retrieve it, it shows the getter is called on 'null'.

The following is the error I am getting:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Home(dirty,
> dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope],
> state: _HomeState#0a2b0):
>
> The getter 'name' was called on null.
>
> Receiver: null
>
> Tried calling: name

Following are the relavent code snippets:

Home Screen build method:

```
final userAuthProvider = Provider.of<UserAuthProvider>(context);
```

Home screen widget causing the error:

```
CustomText(text: userAuthProvider.userModel.name,size: 22,),
```

UserAuthProvider Class relevant code:

```
enum Status { Uninitialized, Unauthenticated, Authenticating, Authenticated }

UserAuthProvider.initialize() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen(_onStateChanged);
  }

Future<void> _onStateChanged(User firebaseUser) async {
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      _status = Status.Uninitialized;
    } else {
      _user = firebaseUser;
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
      _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(firebaseUser.uid);
    }
    notifyListeners();
}
```

UserServices Class getUserById method code:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) =>
      _firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
        return UserModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
      });
```

UserModel Class constructor code:

```
UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _name = snapshot.data()['name'];
    _phoneNumber = snapshot.data()['phoneNumber'];
    _email = snapshot.data()['email'];
    _password = snapshot.data()['password'];
    _id = snapshot.data()['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue!

The correct way to retrieve data is

```
UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _name = snapshot['name'];
    _phoneNumber = snapshot['phoneNumber'];
    _email = snapshot['email'];
    _password = snapshot['password'];
    _id = snapshot['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is no reference to "userModel", but I suppose it is a getter that looks like:

```
UserModel get userModel => _userModel;
```

Right? If that's the case try by updating as follows your getByUserId:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) =>
    UserModel.fromSnapshot(await _firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id).get());
```

Comment: Yes there is a getter for UserModel like you mentioned, but your solution didn't work. I would appreciate other ideas! Thanks